# How and when to make use of the cmake 3.18 option Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

## Current situation

The Cmake 3.18 official documentation states:

> If Boost was built using the boost-cmake project or from Boost 1.70.0
> on it provides a package configuration file for use with
> find_package’s config mode. This module looks for the package
> configuration file called BoostConfig.cmake or boost-config.cmake and
> stores the result in CACHE entry “Boost_DIR”. If found, the package
> configuration file is loaded and this module returns with no further
> action. See documentation of the Boost CMake package configuration for
> details on what it provides.
>
> Set Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE to ON, to disable the search for boost-cmake.

## Problem description

It may make sense for experts in cmake, but as this explanation lacks broader context explanation, it does not really help the cmake beginner.

## Question

Could someone expand on this documentation ? For example, why to set Boost_NO_CMAKE to ON, when the default behavior could be problematic, and how to set the option for best practice ?

## Basic answer

For example, there are some basic explanations [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/73007718-boost-1-70-0-broken) on the fact that Boost 1.70 comes with a new way of using Boost with CMake, that is making use of the Boost BoostConfig.cmake rather than the one coming from the CMake distribution.

Old way:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread timer)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ...)

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ...)

target_link_libraries(...
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ...)
```

New way:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE OFF)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread timer)

target_link_libraries(...
    Boost::thread
    Boost::timer
    ...)
```

Expanding on this information (for example how to make the changes when we don't have control of the code projects, or how to ensure retro-compatibility) would definitely be useful for non-experts in cmake.

Comment: A better way: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED CONFIG COMPONENTS ...)` -- enforce _Config Mode_ for new Boost package finding (no need to use/set the mentioned variable at all) and completely forget about CMake's shipped finder. It's gonna be deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: @zaufi thanks. And how to adapt packages implementing the old cmake way when we don't have control on them ?

Comment: In the case, you don't have control over the sources you definitely can't change variables into imported targets. So, you can use this variable and some others documented in the [`find_package` manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) (like prefer _Module Mode_ and maybe some search-related things) to keep backward compatibility and pass them via CMake CLI at the configure step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Boost wasn't supporting CMake officially, the latter had its own `FindBoost.cmake` module. With every Boost release, the CMake team ought to fix it for the latest Boost version and some other things, so the updated module get available only w/ next CMake release. The shipped module used in [*Module Mode*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature-and-module-mode) of the `find_package` dedicated to packages w/o full-functional CMake support.

Since (relatively) recently, Boost has its official CMake support providing the `BoostConfig.cmake` module used by `find_package` in *Config Mode*. However, depending on CMake settings, the used `find_package` signature and Boost version(s) installed the find result may vary.

The `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` prevents the `FindBoost.cmake` module from use of `BoostConfig.cmake`. Meaning that whatever Boost version installed and found, even if it has the "native" CMake support -- `FindBoost.cmake` should ignore it (i.e., the module, not the found result).

Why? Because even if the CMake team tries to keep its `FindBoost.cmake` backward compatible w/ older CMake/Boost releases and synchronized w/ the modern Boost at the same time there is a possibility to face with a difference in their behavior. To give a user (who cares about compatibility) the full control over what and how to find (via `FindBoost.cmake`) the mentioned variable has added.

Comment: "*However, depending on CMake settings, the used find_package signature and Boost version(s) installed the find result may vary.*"
Does it mean that there is no way to make a CMake script that whatever versions of Boost/Cmake versions are present, is always functional ? I still struggle to understand how to make a stable cmake line that "simply" finds boost and links the targets to it.